# Shortest path algorithm for multiple AGVs in python

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, shortest-path

I'm trying to find a solution for my shortest path problem. I have two vehicles (AGVs) in a small 9 node system. The AGVs need to get from the start to finish position without getting in the way of each other.

[Picture of 9-node-system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgVgZ.jpg)

Is there an algorithm that is easy to implement in python to find the shortest path for two vehicles(shortest path for the system)? The paths need to be non intersecting to avoid collusion.

When working with only one vehicle I used the Dijikstra algorithm. Now with two I could obviously let one of them choose the shortest path and block the route for the other one. But in such a small system, the other AGV would probably end up waiting until the first one is finished. I'm sure there must be a better solution. In my research I couldn't find algorithm that solves it and that's not complicated to implement.

Thank you for your help!

**UPDATE#1**:
I tried putting Tassles suggestions into code. But since I'm pretty new to programming, I was struggling quite a bit and I'm sure I'm still way off.
So I have loads of questions and hope you can help me along the way.

- About the edge: Where do I add the edges to? I guess to E'(e_new) but I don't know in what form.
- How do I include the "every neighbour"? I don't know how to get the neighbours out of map_sparse.
- I struggling to structure the code propperly and use the calculated edges for the dijikstra-algorithm. The way the code is written down below, I don't even use the edge for the shortest distance.
- And I only calculate the shortest path for one of the AGVs but it should be for both at the same time, correct?

Thank you so much, I really appreciate your help!

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations
import itertools
from scipy.sparse.csgraph import csgraph_from_dense
from scipy.sparse.csgraph import dijkstra


class NavigationSystem:
    def __init__(self):
        self.map_sparse = csgraph_from_dense(
            np.genfromtxt('karte.csv', delimiter=',')[2:, 2:])
        self.coordinates = np.genfromtxt(
            'koordinaten.csv', delimiter=',')[1:, 1:]
        self._shortest_distances, self._predecessors = dijkstra(
            self.map_sparse, return_predecessors=True)

    def get_shortest_distance(start, end):
        v_old = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
        e_old = [map_sparse]
        g_old = (v_old, e_old)

        v_new = list(itertools.permutations(v_old, 2))
        e_new = []
        g_new = (v_new, e_new)

        for x in v_new:
            for every neighbour a of x[0]:
                if a != x[1]:
                    e_new.append((a, x[0]))

            for every neighbour b of x[1]:
                if b != x[0]:
                    e_new.append((b, x[1]))

            for every neighbour a of x[0]:
                for every neighbour b of x[1]:
                    if a != b:
                        e_new.append((x[0], x[1]), (a, b))
        return self._shortest_distances[start][end]
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose "not getting in the way" means that both vehicles can not be at the same node at the same time.

In this case, you could model this as a shortest-path problem once again, but this time in a new graph where every vertex represents a pair of vertices in the original graph, i.e. the position of both vehicles.
So let `G = (V,E)` denote your original graph, and construct a new graph `G' = (V',E')` this way:

- `V'` contains all pairs `(u,v)` of vertices in `V` (you can leave out the pairs of the form `(u,u)` if you want, as these will be unreachable anyway).
- Now for the edges, look at what can happen from a position `(u,v)`. Either the first vehicle moves to some position `a != v` for which there is an edge between `u` and `a` in `E`, or the second vehicle moves to some position `b != u` for which there is an edge between `v` and `b` in `E`, or they can both move to `a` and `b` respectively if `a != b`.

In pseudo code you get: (you do this for every pair `(u,v)`)

```
For every neighbour a of u:
  If a != v: 
    Add an edge between (u,v) and (a,v)

For every neighbour b of v:
  If b != u: 
    Add an edge between (u,v) and (u,b)

For every neighbour a of u:
  For every neighbour b of v:
    If a != b: 
      Add an edge between (u,v) and (a,b)
```

Then, you can look for a shortest path between `(s1,s2)` and `(t1,t2)`, where `s1` and `s2` are the two starting vertices and `e1, e2` are the target vertices. If you want to allow both vehicles to start or to end at the same vertex you will have to add the necessary edges to makes `(t,t)`.

You get a number of vertices in `G'` that is the square of the number of vertices in `G` so you can expect the runtime on big instances to be approximately squared also (with most algorithms for finding the shortest path). However, 9 vertices is tiny, so no worries here.

As a side note, when working on a square grid (or on any graph with only edges of the same length) Dijkstra is a bit of an overkill. You can speed things up by doing a simple BFS (Breadth First Search) from your starting position, recording from where you came along the way.

Comment: Hi Tassle, thank you so much for your time and help. I tried putting it into code but was struggling since I'm new to programming. Can you please have a look at my updated post? Thank you very much!